# Why is the "ref" keyword needed when making a call to a function in a DLL?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out why I needed to make a DLLImport function have its parameters as "ref int XXX" instead of just "int XXX". With the latter, this was causing the "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." issue.... but when i added "ref" to the parameters... it works just fine. For example:

```
    [DllImport("someDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int SomeDLL_GetDevices(ref int devices);
```

^ the above works

```
    [DllImport("someDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int SomeDLL_GetDevices(int devices);
```

^ the above crashes and burns

I'm not an export with C++ calls from C# and the marshalling side of it, so if anyone could explain why one works and one doesn't, i'd appreciate it.

Comment: What is the functions signature in C/C++?  The `ref` keyword isn't needed in *general*, it's needed for the particular function you're trying to call.

Comment: I guess the native function is expecting an int pointer, not an int. If you pass the value of `devices` as an int, that value as interpreted as a pointer is unlikely to happen to point to a valid location in memory.

Comment: DWORD SomeDLL_GetDevices (WORD *devices)

Comment: I guess if it was just a WORD it would be int, but WORD * is int pointer which is ref int. Tbh I missed the *... didn't see it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ref int` says "The callee is expecting a pointer to a 32 bit integer, and the marshaller is expecting that to be a managed pointer".

A managed pointer to an integer and an integer are two completely different things. One is pointer-sized -- typically 64 bits -- and one is definitely 32 bits. One is a value, one is a description of where to obtain a variable that contains a value.  They are not interchangeable and you are required to get it right.

If you are unclear on the conventions used by the marshaling layer to get this all right, get clear on it before you write more marshaling code.  **You are interfacing with a system that does not have the type safety or memory safety provided to you by C#, so you are required to ensure that invariants of the runtime are preserved**.  Normally the runtime ensures that the runtime invariants are maintained, but you're describing how to interface with code that's not in the runtime, so make sure it is right.

**Trying stuff until it works is not a good technique**.  You will likely introduce crashes, memory leaks, and more subtle errors (that is, *security holes*) if you continue to do so. Read the documentation, or books, or videos, or get a coworker to explain it to you *so that you understand how it works*. Then you'll be able to write p/invoke code with confidence, rather than guessing and hoping.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Advice taken. Tbh I got confused as I missed where the C++ signature said WORD * instead of WORD. I read it as just WORD that's why i was thinking why put ref there... But I can see it's a WORD pointer i.e. an int pointer. I'll brush up on my primitive type pointer "number of bits" knowledge as I'm flakey on that. Thanks :D

Comment: Although in this context `ref int` is a convention that declares that the function is expecting a pointer to a 32bit integer.

Comment: Yes, rather than ref long which would be expecting a pointer to a 64-bit integer i.e. a long no?

Comment: @slickchick2: Correct.

Comment: Eric what is the answer to your 3 param example? I'm trying to figure out if the marshaller would treat them the same or different for each...

Comment: @slickchick2: If it's a managed pointer to a variable then the runtime knows *everything* about it: whether it is movable, whether it is on the stack or the heap, what the type of the variable is, and so on. If it is an unmanaged pointer, the runtime knows that it is a pointer. If it is an IntPtr, that's just a number; the runtime cannot assume *anything* about it.  This can change what actions the runtime takes when marshaling the value to unmanaged code.

Comment: Sweet, thanks Eric. Why would anyone want to use IntPtr in C# over ref? I can't see an advantage tbh...

Comment: Eric mentions that messing up the signature can cause subtle failures.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4147423/18192) is as an illustrative example of my own subtle failure.  The array I was marshalling seemed to work fine on 32bit machines, but only the first element of the array was accessible when the code ran on a 64bit machine.

Comment: @slickchick2: Suppose the operating system provides an API to, say, load a bitmap. Back in the bad old days, what it would hand you is a pointer to an internal, private Windows data structure that represented the bitmap. Naturally, people figured this out and started *writing* to the private fields via rather than using the APIs to write a robust program because that extra nanosecond makes all the difference to success or failure in the marketplace, not the quality of the software, right?

Comment: @slickchick2: Windows now hands out a pointer-sized integer that is not *necessarily* a pointer. It could be an index into a pointer table, or some other indirection; that's it's business. IntPtr emphasizes that this value is *something you have no business dereferencing*.  A pointer emphasizes *you must dereference this to use it*. So their use cases are opposites.

Comment: I see... so essentially the IntPtr stops people from being silly.... and trying to do things they shouldn't with int pointers...

Comment: @slickchick2: Right. Make sure you understand the difference between `int*` and `IntPtr`.  An `int*` is a value which, when dereferenced, gives you a variable of type `int`.  An `IntPtr` is an integer that is the same *size* as a pointer. Don't fall into the trap of believing that `IntPtr` means anything even vaguely like "pointer to integer", because it does not. The right way to think of it is: Int32 == 32 bit integer, Int64 == 64 bit integer, IntPtr == pointer-sized integer.